# Firefox history.pushState error

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

```
history.pushState(null, null, '?state=1');
```

When trying the above in firefox console, it returns the below error:

```
[19:15:18.029] history.pushState(null, null, '?state=1');
[19:15:18.032] [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMHistory.pushState]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: Web Console :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 1"  data: no]
```

I am not sure why... Also, my webpage which uses History.js returns the same error too. Everything works fine in Chrome.

Firefox 12.0

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: What page are you running that on?  You can't pushState to that state on about:blank, of course....